# Child React Component will not Re-Render

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a Word Clock in React ... However, my child component  does not re-render, despite me sending in a new prop. In order for the correct time to show up I need to refresh the page ...
I read about the component life cycle and I thought I was doing it right but it seems not. My guess is that when I render  in parent component  that this only renders it once and does not re-render even though I am constantly updating the state of this  by setState() every second and updating the time ...
Here is the code: Not working demo, just the app.js file I'm using Facebook's Create-react-app

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dLtedtm0/

Comment: It's a bit difficult to decipher what you're trying to achieve. I'd suggest you to please look at your code once again. You're using ES5 and ES6 React components, which is fine, but you're also confused between ES5 and ES6 type member methods. `componentDidMount() { }` is ES6 way and `componentDidMount: function() { }` is ES5 way of declaring member methods of React components. Please fix so that people can solve your main problem easily. Or better yet, you'll solve it by yourself.

Comment: Yes I know im using both Es5 and Es6 shouldnt matter because Babel will juse compile everything - It's my first React project so I'm trying to mess with a lot of things.

Comment: Not only you're using ES5 and ES6 components, but you're using ES6 member method in ES5 component. You should avoid that at the least. As far as your problem is concerned, @wintvelt has answered it correctly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you could provide some documentation inside your code, to explain what the code is supposed to do.

That said, here are some tips to get you going in the right direction:

- In your `<Text>`, you have a `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` function, which calls `highlight()`. The `highlight` function changes state, based on props. However: at this point props still have the **old** values (because you are inside `componentWillReceiveProps()`. To solve, you could pass `nextProps` to highlight. However, I would advise to remove the state from the Text component entirely.
- Your `<Text>` component has state, but it does not need it: all the different variants of the component are determined by props. So it would be much simpler to put the logic to translate props to whatever you render inside your render function. Then the only lifecycle method in your text component would be `render()`. State is really intended for values that the component itself will change during the lifecycle of the component (e.g. user input in a text field).
- In your clock, in get `getInitialState()` you only return a `showValue`. Later in your code, you also include `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds` to state. Better to include *all* stuff in `getInitialState()` with some initial value, so readers of your code will know what you manage in the state of this component.

Hope this will help you in the right direction..

UPDATE: As a starting point, you can find a simplified [working codepen here](https://codepen.io/wintvelt/pen/GqPPpa?editors=0010), with just the clock component.
It has state (current time), and simply renders the time every second. Hopefully you can start adding code from there.

Comment: I thought I was not suppose to use logic in render functions, which is why I wanted to seperate them out.  In my clock the showdefault, is a state because I plan on changing the color theme of the clock based on user input of click triggered events. I'm going to try and pass next props to highlight and see if it will work, thank you!

Comment: However, I do not think that is the problem I don't think I am constantly sending in new props do you think that is right?

Comment: It would help if you could trim down your Fiddle (eg remove most of the `if then else` stuff), and add comments what you want the code to do. Also, some more descriptive names of variables would help, eg it is not clear to me what the purpose of the generic variable `this.props.val` is.

Comment: I think using `nextProps` instead of `props` will solve: if you send the old props == the same values, react will conclude that nothing has changed, and react will therefore not re-render.